# what is the matching function to call for push_back here refers to?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Solution
{
// you only need to find one solution , thats why we used break    
public: 
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& num,int target)
    {
        vector<int>result;
        for(auto i = num.data();i!=num.data()+num.size();++i)
        {        
            auto vec2 = find(i+1,num.data()+num.size(),target-*i);
            if (vec2!=(num.data()+num.size()))
            {
                result.push_back(i-num.data());
                result.push_back(vec2-num.data());
                break;
            }    
        }
        return result;    
    }    
};
```

guys my doubt is on this lines :

```
result.push_back(i-num.data());
result.push_back(vec2-num.data());
```

when I run above two lines of code it runs fine.

but when I change above two lines of code into this :

```
result.push_back(i);
result.push_back(vec2);
```

it shows the error that says no matching member function for call to push_back.
Isnt that both shows position of the vector ?
My Intuition here is to push_back position values of i and vec2 to vector results.
This is also my answer to my first twoSum leetcode problem.
Guys please help me on this one,i find it very hard to distinguish between above 4 lines.
Advance thanks, and sorry for your time!

Comment: Suggestion: Use the actual types of `i` and `vec2` when declaring them, instead of `auto`. That will make it more obvious why the compiler does not see them as `int`.

Comment: makes sense, thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<int> data()` is of type `int *` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data, you used `auto` to declare `i` from that, so it is also an `int *`

`result.push_back(i-num.data());` is doing a difference of two pointers, that is fine.

`result.push_back(i);` is doing something weird (trying to insert an int pointer into a vector of ints). If you want the index of the element, the pointer difference is the correct way to do it.

Comment: dude, thanks man! this is more than enough, appreciate your time bro.